# Update HTML page with new content upon POST Request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want HTML page been updated after POST request in NODE app with new content,
without using:
additional modules like express etc
forms
new routes

new content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Updated Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Clicked</h1>
      <p>Clicked</p>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

full code is here:

```
const http = require('http');

// create a server to handle requests
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // handle POST requests
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let body = '';

    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log('Received data:', chunk);
      body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Received complete data:', body);


          // send an updated HTML response to the client
  const responseHtml = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Updated Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Clicked</h1>
      <p>Clicked</p>
    
    </body>
  </html>`;

        // send a success response to the client
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(responseHtml);
      });
    } else {
    // send an HTML page to the client that allows them to paste images and videos
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Blue Div</title>
      <style>
        #blue-div {
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background-color: blue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="blue-div" onclick="sendPostRequest()"></div>
    
      <script>
        function sendPostRequest() {
          const data = {};
          fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('POST request successful');

            } else {
              console.error('POST request failed');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending POST request:', error);
          });
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    `);
  }
});

// start the server
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

In DevTools on network tab I'm getting Correct response[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxw9Z.png)

But HTML page stays the same.

I've tried to use
`location.reload();` if response is ok, but it just Reloaded page to initial state while vanishing 'request' itself, i could see appearence for milliseconds

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not creating two routes ?

Comment: @Niro I would like to go without it. just in case I will not find solution I would go with new route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is, that the client does not know what to do with the new page. Using fetch does not trigger a reload like e.g. a post from a form submission.
When you do the reload manually the server responds with the original page.

A solution without multiple routes would be to fetch just the new `<body>` as a string and then on the client side use body's `innerHTML = <the new html from fetch>`

The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) with some examples can be found here.

The code for the first page should then look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Blue Div</title>
      <style>
        #blue-div {
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background-color: blue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="blue-div" onclick="sendPostRequest()"></div>
    
      <script>
        function sendPostRequest() {
          const data = {};
          fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('POST request successful');
              response.text().then(html => {
                document.body.innerHTML = html;
              });
            } else {
              console.error('POST request failed');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending POST request:', error);
          });
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Personally I would suggest that you use a templating engine or at least save the HTML bits in dedicated files. Having them in the server code gets messy very fast.

Comment: could you provide more detailed code here after `if (response.ok){` because I've tried to do that, but it did not work out.   there are 2 points I would like to add (i've made it work in similar fashion you provided - by tweaking client side code and using innerHTML property) (is there any Ideas if that possible to do changes on so called 'server' side like triggering to update HTML with RESPONSE CONTENT)

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean with your second point. But if you want to update the user interface based on something that happens on the server and is not related to any http request, then you need to use webso ckets or server send events. Personally I only use websockets.

Comment: `            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('POST request successful');
              response.text().then(html => {
                document.body.innerHTML = html;
              });` this one worked. in your version just need then to work, at least for me. may be i did not get your comments. In this case websockets is definetely overkill.